# Импорт данных по расписанию

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть два MS SQL сервера. Линкед между ними делать долго (в контексте рабочей обстановки).
Есть дефолтный инструмент импорта данных, где указывается Источник и Получатель данных.

Как эту процедуру поставить на расписание?

Comment: Сохранить как пакет SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) и подсунуть его планировщику SQL Agent.

Comment: а если ваш дефолтный инструмент это некий скрипт/софтина, то воспользоваться стандартным виндовым планировщиком.